# ServiceFabric Windows cluster unable to create firewall rules

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've recently upgraded an on premise Service Fabric cluster to 5.1.156.9590 running on Windows Server 2012 R2. I removed the original cluster and created a new one. Unfortunately my new cluster doesn't seem able to create the firewall rules for any ports specified in the service manifests. The only warning I see that seems connected is this from the ServiceFabric Hosting:

Did not enable firewallpolicy for current profile 1

I can't find any help regarding this message. I'm wondering if something has changed as regards specifying ports for a service or there's something on the node boxes that I haven't configured correctly.

Any pointers appreciated as I'm sure I didn't have to open them manually previously.

Comment: this might be better asked on superuser.com or serverfault.com as its an operational issue rather than a programming one.

Comment: @user3788685 such issues are pretty common with Service Fabric as it is relatively new technology and every update causes some instability. Pat will find an answer here more likely than on other sites.

Comment: Thanks @cassandrad. I should really post this on the MS ServiceFabric board too. I've seen other posts about not being able to upgrade a standalone cluster but I'd hoped fully removing the cluster would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I had the same problem and didn't succeed in reanimation of Service Fabric. Only moving to Azure helped to resolve the issue. You can try next things:

- Completely remove SF, SDK, related services, firewall rules and directory SFData on C drive, then install everything again.
- Check that firewall is enabled
- Check that SF service is created and able to start
- If the service is not able to start, check events, there is a special folder for SF where you can find additional and detailed infromation
- If you have customized the address on which listeners will listen in SF cluster config, try to change it on something different and see if SF would deploy or not